# yarn monorepo not downloading other package's dependencies

Tags: reactjs, eslint, hadoop-yarn, monorepo, workspace

Hello I'm fairly new to monorepo so I have a question

My setup currently looks like this

```
.
├── app
│   ├── web01 (next.js)
│   └── web02 (react.js CRA)
├── packages
│   ├── eslint-config
│   └── ui (vite.js)
├── yarn.lock
└── package.json
```

So what I download devDependencies & peerDependencies for eslint-config with eslint, eslint-config-next, eslint-config-react and so on..

After that, I downloaded eslint-config `"@test/eslint-config": "workspace:^"` web01, web02, and ui workspaces as devDependencies and ended up getting this error message

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.56.0

ESLint couldn't find the plugin "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin".

(The package "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory ...

The plugin "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" was referenced from the config file in ".eslintrc » @test/eslint-config/react".
```

I thought that after downloading the package (I already downloaded eslint-plugin-react in @test/eslint-config), it automatically link to package's devDependencies but I guess I have to download all the devDependencies from the other package's devDependencies.. which doesn't make sense..

I DO NOT want to download all devDependencies that other package already downloaded!

Any idea's on sharing dependencies? any better suggestions instead of making a "library"?

Comment: Please share if you found any solution. I am also getting the same error.

Comment: @PathikGandhi Unfortunately It was just a version issue. Try lower version of eslint, typescript, blah blah blah. Also, try to match all the lint versions throughout the whole project.